# Pyspark automatically set column as nullable even when the schema specifies its not (only when reading a file)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a text file I want to read and make some transformations on, there are no empty lines in the file, and I want to let spark know that to avoid "IsNotNull" checks during them

For the purpose of the question, "some_file.txt" only has a single line with a word in it

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

from pyspark.sql import types as T
my_schema = T.StructType([T.StructField("word", T.StringType(), False)])
spark.read.schema(my_schema).text("some_file.txt").printSchema()

root
 |-- word: string (nullable = true)
```

So that's the issue, I specified in my schema that `word` is not nullable, pyspark still makes it nullable

When I try the same from data instead of a file it works fine

```py
data = [{'word': "hello"}]
spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=my_schema).printSchema()

root
 |-- word: string (nullable = false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because [`text`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.text) does not accept schema. It only uses the column name but text generate only one column as string + partition columns :

> Loads text files and returns a DataFrame whose schema starts with a string column named “value”, and followed by partitioned columns if there are any.